# UIView Transitions Animations

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hai all,

SecondView *sv=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:sv animated:YES];

i like change the default animation (pop up from bottom) to fade or UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation at [apple's iphone dev site](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Sets the modalViewController property
>   to the specified view controller.
>   Resizes its view and attaches it to
>   the view hierarchy. The view is
>   animated according to the transition
>   style specified in the
>   modalTransitionStyle property of the
>   controller in the modalViewController
>   parameter.

here are your options if you want to use what Apple gives you:

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
   UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

anything else, and you'll have to do it manually, which isn't too hard.  First load your new view in the current or a new view controller.  Set it to its initial state, start an animation block, call:

```
+ (void)beginAnimations:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context
```

do whatever transformations you want then:

```
+ (void)commitAnimations
```

more info on the documentation for UIView:

[UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle). Basically what you need is:

```
sv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

Comment: is there any way to implement animation similar to the animation what we are getting when we use UINavigationController (slide in from left) ?